# Is it possible to combine reports in MS access?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have different reports in Access for different cities. Every city has 8 pages (means 8 different reports).

Is it possible in Access to combine reports (8 pages of a city) together to see all the pages together and not as separate reports?

Comment: You have different 8 different reports per city?  I.E., different layouts and details displayed per-report?  Is the goal to just allow the different reports to flow together with the same paging (potentially multiple reports per-page)?  Or just to simply the report process, that only 1 report needs to be run instead of 8?

Comment: Hi. I am creating a website report (page) for cities. Every page has different layout and text and thats why I created different reports. Now I just want to stack them one below the other to make one report with all the city pages together.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to put each report as a full page subreport of a new master report.

If you put a hidden control on the master report you can link child and master fields so each subreport shows the same city.

you can even bind the master report to the list of cities so each one shows in sequence.